# codeigniter destroying session after adding ckeditor latex code in cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ckeditor, latex

I am working on codeigniter project of online exams. I am creating optional question bank.
For adding multiple options i am single ck editor in which after creating option i am inserting option in codeigniter cart.
option is html of ck editor.

But when i am using latex equation in ckeditor as option, i am logging out.
its destroying my user login session. Normal html works fine.
who to overcome this problem?

```
 <Script>
var option_html=CKEDITOR.instances['option'].getData()
$.post(base_url+"question_bank/questions/add_option",
        {option_html:option_html,is_correct:is_correct}
        ,
         function(data)
          {
             //code
          }
        );
</script>

php code
$data = array(
                       'id'      => uniqid(),
                       'qty'     => 1,
                       'price'   => "1",
                       'name'    => $is_correct,
                        'options' => array('type' => 'question_option',
                                            'option_id'=>'',
                                          'option_html' => $option_html)
                    );

                $this->cart->insert($data);
```

Comment: default sessions uses cookies which are limited to 4K, you might be hitting this limit so it's kicking you out, try using native session library.

Comment: oh right admad, latex equation converts to an image which might crossing limit of 4k

Comment: any solutions you have?

Comment: Just search for 'native session codeigniter' you'll find a plenty of drop-in replacement libraries that will get you working without changing any code.

Comment: i got answer there is no problem of cookie size.
change value of product_name_rules in cart to '[:print:]';
change config to use database for session
open ckedior/plugins/eqneditor/dialogs/eqneditor.js and remove statement a.setAttribute('alt')

Answer (score 1):

i got answer there is no problem of cookie size. change value of product_name_rules in cart to '[:print:]'; change config to use database for session open ckedior/plugins/eqneditor/dialogs/eqneditor.js and remove statement a.setAttribute('alt')